# Can I target CE 4.2 or CE 5.0 using C++ on VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-c++, windows-ce

I am developing for a SH4 based device that can run either CE 4.2 or CE 5.0.  As per my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142237/can-standardsdk-4-0-under-evc-be-used-to-debug-on-a-remote-device), I can target these devices using the Standard SDKs under embedded visual C++ 4.0, but I cannot debug over ActiveSync.

I have also loaded Visual Studio 2008 (SP1), but cannot load these SDKs up, and hence cannot target my device.  Is there any way of doing so, or is anyone aware of any other third party debugger I could use.

The application is C++ / MFC.

Comment: Do you mean WinCE 4.2 and WinCE 5.0 here?  There's no .Net Compact Framework 4.2 or 5.0 that I'm aware of.

Comment: My mistake, yes CE 4.2 or CE 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not fix your first problem, but go to the properties page for your project, and click the Devices tab.  Uncheck the "Deploy the latest version of the .Net Compact Framework ... " checkbox.  It's been awhile since I worked with WinCE, but I seem to remember that having this box checked prevented debugging (the app runs fine from the IDE, but the breakpoints show up as open red circles and they never get hit.

I have no answer to your second question, sorry.